# Strange behavior of this simple C file using Visual Studio that creates an Empty list ( 'segmentation fault (core dumped)' - 'nullptr' )

Tags: c, list, nullpointerexception, segmentation-fault, malloc

Hi I'm still a total noob about C programming. I'm actually studying lists, and I tried with the following code to understand their behavior. When I compile it and get to terminal, it exits from terminal with a strange value that is not 1 as if 'malloc()' did not create a correct pointer. I do not get the text of the last 'printf()' in case program worked well either. By debugging it, I get a 'segmentation fault (core dumped)' error and an 'p is nullptr' exception. I originally made a more complex code but it gave this error, then I decided to reduce it to this basic code to find the error. I'm sure I'm misunderstanding something about logic behind struct's pointer.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    int *v;
    int last;
    int length; 
} t_list;

t_list *p;
t_list list;

void makenullList(t_list *p, int dim);

int main(void) {
    int dim;

    printf("put dim: ");
    scanf("%d", &dim);
    getchar();
    printf("\n\n");

    makenullList(p, dim);

    free(p->v);
}

void makenullList(t_list *p, int dim) {

    if ((p->v = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * dim)) == NULL) {
        printf("error");
        exit(1);            
    }

    printf("success\n\n");
}
```

Comment: You need to allocate memory for `p` before you allocate memory for `v`, or ... define `p` as `t_list p`.

Comment: Ok it works if i use variable 't_list p' as parameter for the function. I still don't understand what do you mean for allocating memory for pointer 'p'. Shouldn't pointer 'p' simply be defined as ' t_list *p ' in order to access to pointer 'v' in struct ' t_list ' ?

Answer (score 2):

Allocate memory to p before passing it to function.

Also, free `p` in main(), but after `free(p->v)`.

Comment: Thanks i understood finally!

Answer (score 0):

First solution, you can use `t_list list` then using the reference when you call the function `makenullList`:

```
makenullList(&list, dim);
```

Remember never free `list`.

Second solution, using the pointer, but you have to allocate for it. In this case, you have to allocate `p` in main function, not in `makenullList` function.

```
p = malloc(sizeof(t_list));
if(!p)
  exit(-1);
```

Never cast the `malloc` as you did in your code:

```
p->v = malloc(sizeof(int) * dim) // Do not cast (int *) here
```

When you do not still use p, do not forget free it:

```
free(p->v);
free(p);
```

Comment: thank you very much, in the end i understood. You were very clear!